# What's method for checking user fan of a page in GRAPH API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

In graph api, [Pages.isFan](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan) method not working, what's method for checking user fan of a page in graph api?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us some code? I've tried it in the console and it's working just fine.

Comment: i havent any code, can you give example fql for checking user is fan?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**
To check if the current user is a fan of the Facebook page on landing at your tab check this [answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page/5331541#5331541).

---

**UPDATE:**
You can use the `likes` connection to check if a user is a fan of a page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/PAGE_ID
&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This would return either an empty data array:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Or if fan:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Real Madrid C.F.
                    [category] => Professional sports team
                    [id] => 19034719952
                    [created_time] => 2011-05-03T20:53:26+0000
                )

        )

)
```

So this is how we check using the PHP-SDK:

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/PAGE_ID");
    if( !empty($likes['data']) )
        echo "I like!";
    else
        echo "not a fan!";
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_likes'
  ));
}

// rest of code here
?>
```

Similar script usingJS-SDK:

```
FB.api('/me/likes/PAGE_ID',function(response) {
    if( response.data ) {
        if( !isEmpty(response.data) )
            alert('You are a fan!');
        else
            alert('Not a fan!');
    } else {
        alert('ERROR!');
    }
});

// function to check for an empty object
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Code taken from my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/).

---

While `pages.isFan` is still working for me, you can use the FQL [`page_fan`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) table with the new PHP-SDK:

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    "method"    => "fql.query",
    "query"     => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=$user_id AND page_id=$page_id"
));
if(!empty($result)) // array is not empty, so the user is a fan!
    echo "$user_id is a fan!";
```

From the documentation:

> To read the page_fan table you need:
>
> - any valid `access_token` if it is public (visible to anyone on Facebook).
> - `user_likes` permissions if querying the current user.
> - `friends_likes` permissions if querying a user's friend.

Comment: I've written an in-depth tutorial about [Checking if user is a fan](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/)

Comment: Note that at least at the time of writing I ran into an issue where if the page was created by me, I couldn't get a like status for myself despite FB showing the page as liked. If I tried with another account then like status was shown as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page/5100287#5100287) that relies on the signed_request POST variable that Facebook sends to every tab app page (if you have the "OAuth 2.0 for Canvas" advanced option turned on.

The nice thing about this is you don't need to send another fql.query.

Comment: The migration option you mentioned is only needed for canvas apps, Page Tab apps will always receive a signed_request

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use fbml if you whant for example show some content if they are fan or made some dinamic stuff.

example:

```
<fb:fbml version="1.1">
    <fb:visible-to-connection>This part is visible for fans only!
        <fb:else>This part is visible for non-fans</fb:else>
    </fb:visible-to-connection>
</fb:fbml>
```