# Determine if a user is a Fan of MY page

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-like

I'd like to determine whether a user is a fan of MY facebook page, without getting any Facebook-connect permissions from them first.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must request and be granted access to a user's like data.

One caveat to this - if a user has liked your page, this will be passed to any application tab on your page that the user visits.

Answer (score 1):

3 ways are available to check if user likes a or your page.

----------edit 11/19/2011

1. Signed Request - When a user selects your Page Tab, you will receive the signed_request parameter with one additional parameter, page. This parameter contains a JSON object with an id (the page id of the current page), admin (if the user is a admin of the page), and liked (if the user has liked the page).
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating
2. GraphAPI with user_likes permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
3. FQL with user likes permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/
   **Belongs:**
   You can check if a User likes a specific page by issuing an HTTP GET to /PROFILE_ID/likes/PAGE_ID. This will return, in the data array, an object with the following fields if the user is connected to the page:

---

Using Graph API and php
[What's method for checking user fan of a page in GRAPH API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970439/whats-method-for-checking-user-fan-of-a-page-in-graph-api)

Comment: -1. I've explicitly stated "without getting any Facebook Connect permissions first"

Comment: i understand alex, no need to vote me down.  These are the new Facebook methods.  You used to be able to use the signed request but there is not documentation on this now.

Comment: The vote down is not for delivering the bad news, but for ignoring an explicit statement in the question. The correct answer seems to be "no this is not possible."

Comment: Sorry Alex, i was under the impression that your website was not just meant for single word answers but to delve in all possible solutions for future users.  EG someone is looking for a way to check if one is fan, they just found 2 current available methods.  You can remove my post if you need to.  Also you can get the status of fan using the signed request which i mentioned above.